# Android put extra doesn't send extras to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I try to send some values to another activity.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
             Intent intent  = new Intent(GroupsMain.this, AboutGroup.class);
                intent.putExtra("groupName", "Hello");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

And so on AboutGroup activity I try to get extra. 
1 way:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = extras.getString("groupName");
```

and second way:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
       String name = intent.getStringExtra("groupName");
```

But nothing works for me. On AboutGroup activity i get empty string. Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the degugger and seeing what really is inside of `getIntent().getExtras()`? Also, if you make a `new Intent()` on the second Activity, yes, that has nothing in it

Comment: It is recommended to use a constant (static final) for the extra name, to avoid misspelling it. Also, have you tried simply using getIntent().getStringExtra() ?
Whatever the problem is, there is not enough code here to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

Send:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("groupName", "Hello Anna");
startActivity(intent);
```

get extra:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("groupName");
myTextview.setText(name);
```